# GitLab CI change variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I use `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` GitLab predefined variable for the docker image tag name

example

```
/kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

Unfortunately, some of the characters that could be in `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` is not allowed to use as docker tag

Is it possible to change the value of `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` like delete or change some characters?

Comment: You can use `sed` to perform search and replace operations : `/kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$(sed "s/search/replace/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/g)`

Comment: Do you have an example tag? Maybe it makes sense to revise the tagging strategy

Comment: @leoschet tag example feature/My-project-123. For the docker image I want to have a tag feature_My-project-123

Comment: @Hassan is it real `sed` syntax? I've never seen such usages of sad command, only for files

Answer (score 2):

GitLab provides `CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` which is:

> `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` lowercased, shortened to 63 bytes, and with everything except `0-9` and `a-z` replaced with `-`. No leading `/` trailing `-`. Use in URLs, host names and domain names.

You can check what variables are available here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Comment: Good solution. The drawback is for tags like 2.0 it will post an image with tag 2-0

Comment: Yes, on the bright side it is DNS ready. An alternative would be to go with Hassan's comment